# Different image sizes in a fixed sized container

Tags: asp.net, html

I am re-sizing an image after a user uploads it to maintain its aspect ratio but be no more than 200 pixels wide or 200 pixels high.

I am then displaying the image in an ASP.Net `Image` control. How do I prevent the images from affecting the surrounding elements? I tried setting the `Width` property and `Height` property of the control but that just re-sizes the image itself. Is there maybe a way to wrap the control in a `div` with a fixed width/height?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to resize the image based on aspect ratio, but leave a border in order to fill the 200x200 size. This can then be embedded in the page with the same dimensions without affecting layout.

Alternatively you can just set the `overflow` property of your surrounding `div` to hidden, and set the `div` `Width/Height`. However it depends how to want this to look. Something like:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 200px">
   ...
</div>
```

If you are actually saying you want an image sized `200px` x `400px` to display in full - then just set `Width` to `200px`.